# Remove Scroll Binding Without Removing Others with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, event-handling, scroll

Is there a way to remove the binding below, without removing other bindings on that element that deal with scroll?  I tried the `unbind('scroll', scrollHandler)` and it didnt work also.  I have another scroll binding that is removed because of this. Is there a way to do this with a namespace?

```
var scrollHandler = function () {
     // Inner Logic
};

windowElement.unbind('scroll').scroll(scrollHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using this.

```
windowElement.unbind('scroll.fixedTop').bind('scroll.fixedTop', scrollHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on()` and `off()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/STPcy/

```
var handler1 = function() {
    console.log('handler1');
};

var handler2 = function() {
    console.log('handler2');  
};

$('#myDiv').on('click', handler1);
$('#myDiv').on('click', handler2);

$('#myDiv').off('click', handler1);
```

This results in only `handler2()` being called.